# How can I set up Firebase without IDFA collection using direct SDK download?

Tags: firebase, idfa

I have Firebase set up in my iOS app. I don't use CocoaPods, so I integrate using the direct download of the framework zip file, as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/download/ios).

On their [Configure Analytics Data Collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection?platform=ios#objective-c_1) page, they say you can disable IDFA collection either by not including the AdSupport framework in your app or using `pod 'Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport'` in a Pod file. I need AdSupport in my app for reasons independent of Firebase. How can I achieve `pod 'Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport'` using the direct SDK download zip?